# Track folder locally with Git, Don't track folder on GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control

This seems like an obvious question but I can't find the answer I need anywhere.

I have a folder on my local machine. I would like to track it locally with Git.

When I push to GitHub, I would like to not track/push that folder.

Is this possible/How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @bernie Adding a directory to `.gitignore` prevents it being tracked, and the OP asked how to track it locally.

Comment: @phd: ah, thanks. Misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tracked*, in Git, means *in the index*.<sup>1</sup>  Only *files* can be tracked this way, not folders, because Git does not store folders.<sup>2</sup>

So: what the heck is "the index" anyway?  Well, this eventually gets complicated—the index has a bunch of different roles, with one complex one used during merging—but to put it very simply, the index, in Git, holds your *proposed next commit*.

The index starts out holding copies<sup>3</sup> of all of your files from some commit.  That is, you pick some commit to "check out", with `git checkout name` or `git checkout hash-id`.  This *commit* holds a bunch of files.  Git copies (see footnote 3) *all* of those files into the index, and then also into your *work-tree*.

The *work-tree* or *working tree* is where you *see* and *use* files in Git.  But the files in your work-tree aren't actually in Git at all!

What Git keeps are the *commits*.  Each commit has its own unique hash ID.  When you make a new commit, or anyone makes any commit, Git assigns that commit its own new unique hash ID, and from then on, *that* hash ID means *that* commit.  These commits, once made, can never be changed.  They're all-or-nothing: you either have that hash ID in your Git, in which case you have *that* commit, or you don't have that commit at all.

This makes commits great for archiving: every version of every file that you, or anyone, ever saved, is available for future inspection or re-use forever!<sup>4</sup>  To save space and for other good reasons, though, they're stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed format.  Only Git itself can *extract* them, and of course, being read-only like this, nobody can *change* them.

So this means commits are useless, on their own, for getting any actual *work* done.  You have to have Git *extract* the commit somewhere so that you can work with and/or on it.

That *somewhere* is your work-tree.

Because your work-tree is *yours*, you can stick files into it that Git *doesn't* have saved in any commits.  You pick some commit with `git checkout` and have Git extract all of its files into your work-tree, and then you add some *other* file that *isn't* in the commit.  **In your case, for instance, you first make a folder named `drafts/` and then create a file within this `drafts/` folder.**  Now there is some file that:

- is not in the current commit ...
- so Git didn't copy it into the index ...
- but there it is, `drafts/README` or whatever, in your work-tree.

That is, by definition, an *untracked file*.

**If you tell Git to track this file, by copying it into the index, that file will be in your *next* commit.**  And, as [code_fodder said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59472476/1256452), it's the *commits* that get shared.  When you connect your Git to some other Git with `git push`, your Git sends their Git some or all of your commits—ones that you have, that they don't, that you want them to have.  You cannot pick and choose *files* in this process.  You either give them the whole commit—with its complete snapshot of all of its files—or you don't.

**This means that the short answer to your question is just "no".**  It is not possible to track a file—which means it goes into each *new* commit you make—yet have your Git deliver to the other Git some commit that you *didn't* make, that doesn't contain the file.

A longer answer is available though.  You can make commits in which you *do* save `drafts/*` files, and *other* commits in which you *don't* save them.  You can then carefully push only chains of commits in which `drafts/*` files *have never appeared*.

If you ever accidentally push one of the commits in which the `drafts/*` files *do* appear, though, it's very hard to take that back: Git treats commits as fairly precious (see footnote 4) and has a tendency to give *all* commits to *every* other Git that comes along and asks.  That is, if you accidentally send a commit *to* GitHub, and *someone else* comes along and asks GitHub for any new commits that are in that repository, the someone else will get this commit, and now you must plead with that someone else to give it up.  Even if you get GitHub to remove the accidental commit, this other guy has a copy now.

It's also a pretty big pain.  If you have commit `a123456...` (some big ugly hash ID) that *does* have `drafts/file1.txt` in it, and commit `b789abc...` (some other different big ugly hash ID) that *doesn't* have `drafts/file1.txt` in it, then every time you switch from `b789abc...` to `a123456...`, Git will *remove* `drafts/file1.txt` from both the index and your work-tree.  When switching from `a123456...` back to `b789abc...`, Git will copy the file from `b789abc...` back into both the index and your work-tree—as it must; your index holds the proposed *next* commit, and your work-tree should match, at least for all tracked files.

Usually, the right way to do this is to have a *separate Git repository* in which you store these things.  That is, inside `drafts/`, just create a new Git repository.  The outer Git, holding all the other files, will leave all the `drafts/*` files to the inner Git.  You can then just not give anyone else this Git repository at all.  If you want to have some hosting server keep a copy, you can do that separately, and not give people access to the separate repository there.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, it means that when we're referring to *files*.  Git also sometimes says that a branch is set up to "track" another branch.

<sup>2</sup>What happens is that when Git encounters a commit and the commit contains a file named `a/b/c.txt`, Git tells the computer *create a file named `a/b/c.txt`*. To do that, if the computer requires it—obviously yours does—Git will *create* the *folder* named `a`, then *create* the *folder* named `b` within `a`, so that it can create a file named `c.txt` within `b` within `a`.  But to the rest of Git, this is just a file named `a/b/c.txt`.  It never saved "folder `a`" nor "folder `b`", just the *file*.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, the index holds a *reference* to an internal Git *blob object*, for each file.  But it works just as well at this level to just think of the index as if it held a copy of each Git-format file.

<sup>4</sup>It *is* possible to *get rid of* a commit.  It's relatively easy, in fact, up until you yourself with later commits, and/or other people's commits, make things (which in Git means "more commits") that depend on that commit.  Then it gets harder.  So commits *are* completely read-only—no one, nothing, not even Git, can change them—but if you have made a bad one, you can just stop using it.  If you're not using it, and have set things up so that you *can't* use it again, and no one else can use it, Git eventually cleans it up for you.

Answer (score 2):

The folder is either part of your repository or it is not. You push complete commits where each commit is the state of all the files in your repo at a specific time. If you add a folder to your repo and commit it then it is now a part of your repo. If you push it, it goes wherever you push'ed it to...

Here are some options (there are probably others):

- You could have a local branch that you commit locally and don't push that branch to github
- You can move your folder to another repo outside of your current repo - possibly add a symlink to it so that when you push your repo to github it just contains a broken symlink (not pretty but will work).
- You can add your folder to .gitignore file, it will not be part of your repo and won't get pushed, but you can't track it

Maybe you can explain your usecase, usually a repo is a complete set of things - i.e. if you don't want to push it, then it sounds like it should not be part of your repo (this is a generalisation - so it will be interesting to hear what your usecase is)...

Comment: My use case is: I have a local folder called drafts/ that I don't want to expose publicly.

Comment: Oh, in that case, perhaps even better is to create the folder `drafts/` then add that to your `.gitignore` as `drafts/` and then cd into drafts and make that a git repo by `git init` and then commit your changes. This is a repo inside a repo, but since the folder drafts is ignored this acts as a stand alone repo.... that is probably what I would do here...

Comment: I have a use case: a config file that I use in my dev environment, but that no other developer uses -- i.e. warren-config.json .

Comment: @warrens and generally local config files that you don't want to share go into the .gitignore file

Comment: @code_fodder I get how .gitignore works.  The use case is to (1) track my person dev environment config file which works with the repo code, but (2) is a file that no other developer uses.

If there are, say, 10 developers working on a repo, and they each have a personalized config file for running the code in their dev environment then why should each developer see the changes of the other 9?

We have a configs folder with config files for "production", "integration", and one config file for each developer.  Each developer wants to track their own config file -- but not see the others.

Comment: @warrens I guess you want a personalised clone... that's not really how git works and it has not mechanism (that I am aware of) to do this. It just has a pile of files at various states (called a commit) and it does not care about the needs of a specific user of the repo. If you clone the repo you get all the files, so you can either have your config files in the repo or not in the repo. I put global config in my repos and non-global take out/ignore.  What IDE/dev config are you talking about (for a bit of context)?

Comment: e.g. in Qt creator I used to have a global config file with all the useful build settings (release, debug, gdb, various cross compile targets etc....) which would take significant time to setup and so we don't want to repeat that per user. However Qt creator devs then "forced" that this can't be shared by tying the config file to your hardware - thus forcing each user to have their own config (dumb-ass's IMO). I no longer use that IDE. I use VS Code now in which I can share all the useful stuff that I want or not by including different files as per my choice.

Comment: so I gitignore only the ipch/ folder (intellisense). But then vs code is nice because it has both global and project settings. So, all this to say, your issue may not lie within git itself... git does *its* part of this job perfectly

Comment: @code_fodder It's a "devops" thing.  :-)  Each developer's config file is included with an AWS lambda function build image and then gets deployed via terraform to AWS.  So for instance, I can modify my "devwarren" config file for a particular testing situation that controls which S3 buckets the lambda function will use (among other things).  The specific config filename is also used by terraform as its workspace name, and the workspace name is used for naming AWS resources as well.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an obvious answer because git branches are not meant to work this way. When a local branch is pushed to remote, it is done exactly which is the purpose of version control.

If you want to have two different sets of files tracked (e.g. one branch excluding a folder) you could do so with two branches, one that's only kept locally and one that's pushed remotely. By doing this note that you're not getting any backup copy of the local-only branch. You can make a script that commits to the local-only branch and also to the branch excluding a folder that will be pushed.

Comment: This seems like the best option. Any resources for creating the script I'd need to commit to both branches?

Comment: Maybe the simple thing to do is make a script that takes the most recent common on the local-only branch and cherry-pick's it onto the second branch. Afterward it can remove the folder (if it exists) from the second branch's commit. If the commit becomes empty, drop it altogether. You can work this out piece by piece and put them together into a single script. Eventually you could be able to have the script take a range of references of the local-only branch to operate on rather than just the latest commit if you should ever need that ability.